# .htaccess in CodeIgniter - not submiting forms

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I recently modified my .htaccess file into this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.net [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.net/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

This way non-www pages are redirected to www and index.php is removed from my links. But there's a problem: all my forms aren't working. Whenever I press submit button the page reloads and nothing else happents.
If I delete rows 2 and 3 it is working (without redirecting non-www pages to www, obviously).
How can I make this work preperly?

Comment: as you are riding your form? using form helper?

Comment: Yes. Using the form helper. BTW, I changed $config['index_page'] from config.php.

Comment: Correct, I would advise you exactly that. Edit `$config['base_url']`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Forgot about that variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit Variable.

```
$config['base_url']
```